# блок Emojione.min.js

Tags: javascript

Необходимо вставить в чат блок со смайликами, насколько я понял имеется скрипт в три строки

$('#shoutbox-name').emojioneArea({
        pickerPosition:"right"
        })'

который способен решить этот вопрос, но у меня он не работает
 вот код:

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Making a Shoutbox with PHP and jQuery</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/1.3.0/assets/css/emojione.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/styles.css" />

    <style>
    .container{
    width:600px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    }
    </style>

</head>

<body>


    <div class="shoutbox">

        <h1>Shout box <img src='./assets/img/refresh.png'/></h1>

        <ul class="shoutbox-content"></ul>

        <div class="shoutbox-form">
            <h2>Write a message <span>×</span></h2>

            <form action="./publish.php" method="post">
                <label for="shoutbox-name">nickname </label> <input type="text" id="shoutbox-name" name="name"/>
                <label class="shoutbox-comment-label" for="shoutbox-comment">message </label> <textarea id="shoutbox-comment" name="comment" maxlength='240'></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Shout!"/>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/1.3.0/lib/js/emojione.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/script.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('#shoutbox-name').emojioneArea({
    pickerPosition:"right"
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: "но у меня он не работает" - и ***как*** он не работает?

Answer (score 0):

Вы подключили не ту библиотеку. Вам нужна `emojionearea`, а вы подключили `emojione`.

Пример с правильной библиотекой

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#shoutbox-name').emojioneArea({
    pickerPosition: "bottom"
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojionearea/3.4.1/emojionearea.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojionearea/3.4.1/emojionearea.min.js"></script>

<label for="shoutbox-name">nickname </label> <input type="text" id="shoutbox-name" name="name" />
```